# Application of Matrix Diagonalization

Tags: matrices, inverse, diagonalization

I'm reading a book about inverse analysis and trying to figure out how the authors do the inversion.

Assume that matrix $C$ is
$$
  C
~=~
  \begin{bmatrix}
    88.53 & -33.60 & -5.33 \\
    -33.60 & 15.44 & 2.67 \\
    -5.33 & 2.67 & 0.48
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
and at some point authors diagonalize this matrix to calculate matrix $P$ using
$$
  C^{-1}
~=~
  P^{\rm t} L P
$$
where $L$ is a diagonal matrix of positive eigenvalues and the columns of $P$ are orthonormal eigenvectors.

The above equation for diagonalizing inverse of $C$ is a bit different from what is usually used and therefore I cannot calculate $P$ correctly (same as the book!).
So, that would be great if somebody can show me the way to calculate $P$.
$$
  P
~=~
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0.93 & 0.36 & -0.03 \\
    -0.36 & 0.90 & -0.23 \\
    -0.06 & 0.23 & 0.97
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Go to the FAQ section for directions on how to use LaTeX to properly write mathematics here.

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard of [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)

For your matrix:

$$C=\left(\begin{matrix}
88.53 & -33.60 &-5.33\\
-33.60 & 15.44 & 2.67\\
-5.33 & 2.67 & 0.48
\end{matrix}\right)$$

We would find the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors and then diagonalize it such that:

$$C = P J P^{-1}$$

For this matrix, we have:

$\lambda_1 = 101.976, v_1 = (0.929997, -0.362899, -0.0583849)$

$\lambda_2 = 2.47102 , v_2 = (0.366307, 0.901908, 0.228868)$

$\lambda_3 = 0.00312608 , v_3 = (-0.0303981, -0.234233, 0.971705)$

Using these values, we can now diagonalize the matrix $C$.

$$C=\left(\begin{matrix}
88.53 & -33.60 &-5.33\\
-33.60 & 15.44 & 2.67\\
-5.33 & 2.67 & 0.48
\end{matrix}\right) = P J P^{-1}$$

Where:
$$P = \left(\begin{matrix}
0.929997 & 0.366307 & -0.0303981 \\
-0.362899 & 0.901908 & -0.234233 \\
-0.0583849 & 0.228868 & 0.971705
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$J = \left(\begin{matrix}
101.976 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2.47102 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.00312608
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$P^{-1} = \left(\begin{matrix}
0.929997 & -0.362899 & -0.0583849 \\
0.366307 & 0.901908 & 0.228868 \\
-0.0303981 & -0.234233 & 0.971705
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Notice that the columns of $P$ are from the linear combination of the eigenvectors $[v_1 | v_2 | v_3]$.

Notice that $J$ is the diagonal of the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$.

Note the $P^{-1}$ is just the inverse of $P$.

Lastly, you should understand that this works only when a matrix is diagonalizable (see site referenced above).

Regards

Comment: Frustrating...seems the OP has disappeared. Good work, hopefully it clicked! + 1

Comment: @amWhy: Yep, and that was a bit nasty with bad numerical issues. Oh well, hope s/he got it!

Comment: Yes, I can see it gets messy!

Comment: It gets so messy. I always flee when I see these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The spectral theorem ensures that since $C$ is symmetric it has 3 real eigenvalues and its eigenspaces are orthogonal. Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ be the eigenvalues and $\vec v_1,\vec v_2,\vec v_3$ be orthonormal eigenvectors (whose existence is granted by the spectral theorem; note that $\lambda_i$ need not be distinct, since you can always orthonormalize a basis with the [Gram-Schmidt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-Schmidt_process)). $\vec v_i$ are such that $C\vec v_i=\lambda_iv_i$ ($i=1,2,3$): in matrix notation this means
$$
  C
  \begin{bmatrix}
  ~\\
    \vec v_1 & \vec v_2 & \vec v_3
  \\~  
  \end{bmatrix}
~=~
  \begin{bmatrix}
  ~\\
    \vec v_1 & \vec v_2 & \vec v_3
  \\~  
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_1\\
    & \lambda_2\\
    && \lambda_3
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\vec v\in\mathbb R^{3\times 1}$ is intended as a column vector. Therefore, setting
$$
  D
=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_1\\
    & \lambda_2\\
    && \lambda_3
  \end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
  P
=
  \begin{bmatrix}
  ~\\
    \vec v_1 & \vec v_2 & \vec v_3
  \\~  
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
you have that $C=PDP^{-1}$. Since the columns of $P$ are orthonormal, it follows that $P^{-1}=P^{\rm t}$ is the transpose of $P$, therefore
$$
  C=PDP^{\rm t}
$$
Now, if you want to compute any power of $C$ (or just any integer power, if you work with real matrices and $\lambda_i$ are not all non-negative) you have that
$$
 C^n = PD^nP^{\rm t}
$$
(since $P^{\rm t}P=\rm I$, the identity matrix). Chosing $n=-1$ you have
$$
  C^{-1}
~=~
  P
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_1^{-1}\\
    & \lambda_2^{-1}\\
    && \lambda_3^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix}
  P^{\rm t}
$$
so that $L=D^{-1}$.

To sum up, $P$ is the matrix whose $i$-th column is the eigenvector $\vec v_i$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, where $\vec v_1,\vec v_2,\vec v_3$ are orthonormal.

(In your case, since you require $C^{-1}=P^{\rm t}LP$ rather than $PLP^{\rm t}$, $P$ is the matrix whose $i$-th *row* is the eigenvector $\vec v_i$, i.e. the transpose of the $P$ above.